# how to run selenium automation using TAGS in C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I want to run only login scripts,how to run in c#.Attached the java testrunner file

```
@RunWith (Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features ="src/test/java/features",
        glue ={"stepdefinition"},
        plugin ={"html:target/Reports/Html Report/cucumber-html-report", 
                "json:target/Reports/Json Report/cucumber.json",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/Reports/Extent Report/ExtentReport.html"           
                },
        tags = {"@Login"}, monochrome=true,dryRun=false)
enter code here

public class TestRunner {
}
```

Comment: You can usw Select Group By Traits to group the SpecFlow scenarios by the tags defined at the scenario or feature level:

Comment: for more info [click here](http://specflow.org/getting-started/)